# my fan over my table works from wall switch but the light fixtures doesnt come on unless i flip the switch numerous times

Tags: fans, light

my fan over my table works from wall switch but the light on the fan wont come on unless I flip the switch a number of times before light will come on. what is causing this problem. if I use the pull chain on the light I have no problem turning it on and off

Comment: Is this a new behavior?

Comment: Is there a separate wall switch for the fan and light? What type of light bulb is in the fan?  Is the lightbulb fan rated? Have you checked to see if it's screwed in tight?

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual for your fan.

For some fans, this is an ***intended*** feature to allow control of both fan and light from a single light switch.

Answer (score 0):

could be the switch arching contacts or the condenser on the fan or the fan bearings need lubrication. Check the switch first connecting input to the switch onto the outlet (do this with the power off unless you are used to working on a live circuit)